# Minimize Boilerplate Code in PowerShell Module Pester Test files

Tags: powershell, boilerplate, pester

I am building a PowerShell module using the PSModuleDevelopment's MiniModule template generator.  It makes a project that looks like this:

```
PROJECT_ROOT/
├─ the_module_name/
│  ├─ internal/
│  │  ├─ internalFunc.ps1
│  ├─ functions/
│  │  ├─ Get-MyThing.ps1
│  ├─ the_module_name,psd1
│  ├─ the_module_name.psm1
├─ tests/
│  ├─ general/
│  ├─ functions/
│  │  ├─ internalFunc.Tests.ps1
│  │  ├─ Get-MyThings.Tests.ps1
│  ├─ pester.ps1
├─ .gitignore
├─ README.md
```

In my *PROJECT_ROOT/tests/functions/Get-MyThings.Tests.ps1* file I have this block of Pester code to load and unload the module so that I can unit test it:

```
BeforeAll {
    $modName = 'the_module_name'
    Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\..\..\$($modName)\$($modName).psd1" -Force
}

AfterAll {
    Remove-Module -Name $modName
}
```

This works but it feels ugly and repetitive and will be even more so as I add more and more test files.  Is there a better way to minimize the boiler plate or to organize my project?

Comment: Since this code is working, it is not a good fit for SO. This question should be on-topic at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @lit the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need _full code_ rather than a _minimal example, a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and a title that says what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.